# Dynamical drawing images in Cinder (Windows)

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, cinder

I have used Cinder about few weeks and i have some problem.
I am using method "drag-and-drop" in my program :

```
void TutorialApp::fileDrop(FileDropEvent drop){               ///        drop are images
for(size_t i=0; i<drop.getNumFiles();++i){
     Vertex imageVertex = Vertex((Vec2i(drop.getPos().x, drop.getPos().y+200)));
     imageVertex.path = drop.getFiles()[i];
```

and next my step is draw Vertex with associeted image. So that is question: how to add resources in this case, or maybe there is more easy solution? Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Straight to the point:**
First of all,you want to keep images (i.e *[gl::Texture](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.4/classcinder_1_1gl_1_1_texture.html)*)  in your objects, that you want to draw. So in your class Vertex, add this gl::Texture as member. And then I suggest to use [this](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.4/namespacecinder.html#ad49aa427548e365f95336af782c2161a) function to load image and edit constructor, to take gl::Texture as parameter.

So you end up with something like this:

```
class testVertex
{
public:
testVertex(Vec2i _pos, gl::Texture image);

void draw(){

    gl::draw(texture, pos);
}
private:
    gl::Texture texture;
    Vec2i pos;
};
///constructor
testVertex::testVertex(Vec2i _pos, gl::Texture image)
{
    pos = _pos;
    texture = image;
}


class BasicApp : public AppNative {
public:
    void setup();
    void mouseMove( MouseEvent event ); 
    void mouseUp( MouseEvent event );   
    void keyUp(KeyEvent event);
void fileDrop(FileDropEvent event);
void update();
void draw();

//// create container for testVertex
vector <testVertex> mVertices;
}


/// To load images via drop...
void BasicApp::fileDrop(FileDropEvent event){
    gl::Texture fileTexture = loadImage(event.getFile(0));
    mVertices.push_back(testVertex(Vec2i(event.getX(), event.getY()), fileTexture));
}
/// To draw images...
void BasicApp::draw(){
    for (int i = 0; i < mVertices.size(); i++)
    {
        mVertices[i].draw();
    }
}
///
```